# Click on link to navigate another page without header, footer change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

my website has fixed header and footer components. I have a link on body page. when i click on link, it should navigate to another page without changing header and footer component. any one have idea about how to achieve it using jquery/javascript.

Comment: AJAX is what do you need.

Comment: …why do you need jQuery? Why can't you just use a standard link and have the header on all your pages? Or, hell, an iFrame?

Comment: @semsem ;- could you please share any example code?

Comment: @some person :- i dont want to use iFrame here. and i dont want to include header in all pages.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: You can send ajax request to server and load response data in container. (ajax, jquery.load...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a XMLHttpRequest directly to your desired html page, like this:

```
function load_htm()
{
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
//here your content to be loaded
var elem = document.getElementById('content');
//here goes your target html file...
url = "/yourfile.htm";
//this is not the better way to, but will clear the element...
elem.innerHTML = '';
if (xml !== null) {
xml.open('GET', url, true);

    xml.send();
    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xml.readyState === 4) {
        //getting the results and assign to element
        response = xml.responseText;
        elem.innerHTML = response;
        }
    }
}
}
```

html:

```
<div id="footer"></div>
<div id="link" onclick="load_htm();"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="header"></div>
```